# Has anyone attempted to run node.js or raw v8 engine in embedded environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, embedded, embedded-linux

Node.js seems opened up a lot of possibilities on event driven paradigm. I'm curious if there's any effort on porting node.js to embedded o/s such as uc/os? JavaScript syntax would be much more expressive than c when it comes to event driven programming, and I wonder if this actually justify the performance difference?

Any opposing thoughts are welcome too.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why so many people actually want to close this question. I'm merely asking for some insight in a topic i'm interested in, and will accept an answer of in-depth explanation and mind broadening thoughts

Comment: Ultimately it comes down to having sufficient memory, then figuring out and providing equivalents of the operating system and library support it requires. And then you have to decide if performance will be useful.  But likely the main issue is that embedded people tend to have hardware implications in mind, and so don't find untyped languages confidence inspiring.

Comment: @miushock I think the problem is in the way you stated the question. Maybe asking for specific advice like which aspects should you consider when porting V8 or node.js to an embedded platform would be a better question. Also asking for some examples may help.

Answer (score 2):

At least we have a nodejs package in Buildroot (http://www.buildroot.org), which means that people have been running it in embedded environments.

Comment: Very Interesting. I've also found some scattered discussions through searching. It would be nice if someone can actually give a running example in near future.